# Stop a div scrolling once its content finishes, while the other div keeps scrolling

Tags: html, css

Working on a new design with three vertical columns.

1. The leftmost column is fixed
2. The main content column and the right sidebar are vertically scrollable by the browser's main scroll bar parallely.
3. When content of right sidebar reaches end than it stops scrolling while the main Content Column keeps on Scrolling.

Somewhat Similar to Yahoo's Layout

Comment: Can you give us what you have so far? At least set up the html on jsfiddle.net

Comment: So what stopping you?

Comment: Where's the question ?

Comment: @PatsyIssa Well I am unable to figure out how to stop the right sidebar div  from scrolling when its content finishes while the main content column keeps on scrolling using  browser's main scroll bar .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you need is this: http://andrewhenderson.me/tutorial/jquery-sticky-sidebar/

Have a look at the demo: http://andrewhenderson.me/wp-content/tutorials/jquery-sticky-content/index.html

If this doesnt serve your purpose, try googling with keywords 'sticky div' or 'sticky sidebar'. I am sure you'll find what you are looking for!

Comment: @ Sarmad Saleem--Thanks for reply. However--  No I dont want the Sticky widget to behave as  shown in the example suggested by you. Since if the content of the widget itself goes to more than one page, it is not scrolling with the Main Content. Whereas what I am looking for is that  it should too scroll with browser's main scroll bar---- Best eg. is yahoos page--http://www.yahoo.com/

Comment: Oh, my bad! I found this fiddle, see if this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanmaxwell/25QaE/

Comment: --Thanks sarmad for your efforts. This is what I was looking for.